# Get all comments on all issues with label

Tags: github-api

I'm trying to get the GitHub API to give me all the information, including comments, on all the issues with a specific label.

Here's how I can get the issues with that label

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/hadley/dplyr/issues?label=reprex/
```

I can get the comments on a specific issue with

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/hadley/dplyr/issues/2396/comments
```

Is there a way to combine these two calls somehow? This, for instance, does not work

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/hadley/dplyr/issues?label=reprex/comments
```

Answer (score 2):

For others perhaps arriving here years later like myself (now that GraphQL is available for GitHub), here's an example of how I was able to accomplish something similar for my own needs today (using your use case and example values above).

In the [GitHub GraphQL API Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer) (which you may need to additionally "sign in" for and agree to, I think to measure resource limits), add something like the following query code (and hit the play button):

```
{
  repository(name: "dplyr", owner: "hadley")
    issues(
      first: 100
      orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: ASC}
      filterBy: {labels: "reprex"}
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          url
          createdAt
          author {
            login
          }
          body
          comments(first: 100) {
            edges {
              node {
                createdAt
                author {
                  login
                }
                body
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course replacing `dplyr` with your repo, `hadley` with your owner, and `reprex` with your label.

**Note 1**: The `orderBy` values, as well as things like `title`/`url`/`createdAt`/etc are also just optional examples of the kind of elements or parameters I wanted for the returned data (in addition to issue/comment `body`s), but there are lots of other options to potentially use; toggling open the "Docs" panel, the "Explorer" button, or the suggestions near one's cursor where typing seemed to be my friends for discovering new ones.

**Note 2**: If you want comments for pull requests, replace `issues` with `pullRequests` (or duplicate the whole big block under/in `repository`) but also note that many "comments" in PRs are actually "reviews" under the hood, so for my use case I simply made an additional block of `reviews` duplicating what's specified for `comments`, e.g.:

```
          comments(first: 100) {
            ...
          }
          reviews(first: 100) {
            ...
          }
```

**Note 3**: You're apparently limited to 100 matches at a time (though can specify `last` instead of `first`, or use other parameters to further filter/sort), so in cases where I had/needed more issues/PRs to return, I additionally requested `pageInfo` about them:

```
{
  repository(name: "dplyr", owner: "hadley") {
    issues(
      first: 100
      orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: ASC}
      filterBy: {labels: "reprex"}
    ) {
      pageInfo {
        startCursor
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
      edges {
       ...
```

Then used the string value that got returned for `endCursor` for the `after` argument of `issues`. For example, if the data returned `"endCursor": "a1b2c3"`, I'd re-run the query like so:

```
{
  repository(name: "dplyr", owner: "hadley") {
    issues(
      first: 100
      orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: ASC}
      filterBy: {labels: "reprex"}
      after: "a1b2c3"
    ) {
      edges {
       ...
```

to get the next "page" of results. The same would presumably apply to comments/reviews if you had 100+ matching comments/reviews per node.

Answer (score 0):

No, I did not see a way to combine them with the GitHub API alone.

Combining different queries into one is normally done with [GraphQL](https://developer.github.com/early-access/graphql/) (still in early access).

> We're supporting GraphQL because it offers much more flexibility for our integrators.
>   The ability to define and specify precisely the data you want for your integration is a powerful advantage over the existing REST endpoints.